# wp7, select music from device library to put into app

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage, windows-phone-7.1

I was wondering if there was a way to create an app where a user is able to take a song from their wp7 music library and have the app copy it to put into isolated storage.

I have an idea for a music editing app but am unable to find if it's even possible for a user to select his or her own music from the device to use.

(sorry for this not being a coding question... I can assure you there will be some down the line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think this is possible. You can get access to the song in order to play and pause it, but you can't get access to the raw data in the current SDK. (Which means you won't be able to copy the data to isolated storage).